# AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping

Tags: c#, automapper

Estou usando a biblioteca [AutoMapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper/) para mapear minhas ViewModels.

Possuo minha classe **DBDominio**:

```
public class DBDominio
    {

        [Key]
        [Column("ID")]
        public long id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(128)]
        [Column("ID_USU")]
        public string idUsu { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength (200)]
        [Column("URL")]
        public string url { get; set; }

        [StringLength (100)]
        [Column("ID_c")]
        public string idC { get; set; } 

        [StringLength(100)]
        [Column("ID_s")]
        public string idS { get; set; } 
    }
```

E minha viewModel VMDominioDetails:

```
public class VMDominioDetails
    {
        public long id { get; set; }

        public string idUsu { get; set; }

        public string url { get; set; }

        public string idC { get; set; } 

        public string idS { get; set; } 
    }
```

Em meu **Global.asax** eu adicionei  a chamada **AutoMapperWebConfiguration.Configure();**

Minha classe de configuração está desta forma:

**AutoMapperWebConfiguration**

```
public static class AutoMapperWebConfiguration
    {

        public static void Configure()
        {
            Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.AddProfile(new DominioProfile());

            });

            Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
        }
    }
```

E minha classe **DominioProfile**:

```
public class DominioProfile : Profile
    {
        protected override void Configure()
        {

            Mapper.CreateMap<DBDominio, VMDominioDetails>();

        }
    }
```

Ao tentar "mapear", recebo o seguinte erro:

> Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
>
> Mapping types: DBDominio -> VMDominioDetails
>   PROJETO.Models.DBModels.DBDominio ->
>   PROJETO.Models.ViewModels.VMDominioDetails
>
> Destination path: VMDominioDetails
>
> Source value: PROJETO.Models.DBModels.DBDominio
>
> Descrição: Ocorreu uma exceção sem tratamento durante a execução da
>   atual solicitação da Web. Examine o rastreamento de pilha para obter
>   mais informações sobre o erro e onde foi originado no código.
>
> Detalhes da Exceção: AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Missing
>   type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
>
> Mapping types: DBDominio -> VMDominioDetails
>   PROJETO.Models.DBModels.DBDominio ->
>   PROJETO.Models.ViewModels.VMDominioDetails
>
> Destination path: VMDominioDetails
>
> Source value: PROJETO.Models.DBModels.DBDominio

O erro acontece nessa linha, onde `dBDominio` é um objeto do tipo `DBDominio`

```
VMDominioDetails d = new VMDominioDetails();
d = _map.Map<VMDominioDetails>(dBDominio);
```

Já tentei usar uma referencia reversa na configuração para ver se resolveria, ficando assim: `Mapper.CreateMap<DBDominio, VMDominioDetails>().ReverseMap()` , mas não resolveu.

Answer (score 2):

Ricardo eu acabei fazendo um teste e descobri que no `DominioProfile` tem que chamar `CreateMap` dessa forma:

```
public class DominioProfile : Profile
{
     [Obsolete]
     protected override void Configure()
     {
         CreateMap<DBDominio, VMDominioDetails>();            
     }
}
```

então, o `CreateMap` é um método de `Profile`, mas, também outro problema, essa maneira é `obsoleto`, então, deve mudar para isso:

```
public class AutoMapperWebConfiguration
{
    public static void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<DBDominio, VMDominioDetails>();

        });

        Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
    }
}
```

colocando direto no `AutoMapperWebConfiguration`.

No código do `controller` fiz:

```
VMDominioDetails d = new VMDominioDetails();
d = Mapper.Map<VMDominioDetails>(new DBDominio
    {
       id = 100,
       idC = "idc"
    });
```

e foi mapeado corretamente os campos e seus respectivos valores.

Só para terminar no `Global.asax`, fiz a chamada `AutoMapperWebConfiguration.Configure();`:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        AutoMapperWebConfiguration.Configure();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente substituir a linha:

```
d = _map.Map<VMDominioDetails>(dBDominio);
```

por:

```
Mapper.Map(dBDominio,d);
```